# Getting error 4002 when calling tags method without a sort parameter

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

According to the [documentation](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=tags), calling the `tags` method without a `sort` parameter should return the recently used tags, since the default sort is by `activity`.

Instead, I get an error 4002 with the message "The 'sort' query parameter was invalid for this request.".

What is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now.